# Using subqueries in where condition in hive

Tags: hive

I have a query where I have three filter condition with AND function. One of them is using a subquery. Is it possible to use hive 0.13 version to write the subquery in where condition?

```
select * from table a where a.dt > (select add_days(k.clndr_dt, -5) from mantas.kdd_cal k where k.clndr_day_age=0 and k.clndr_nm='SYSCAL') and a.dt <= (select k.clndr_dt from mantas.kdd_cal k where k.clndr_day_age=0 and k.clndr_nm='SYSCAL')
```

this is written in oracle, now we are converting it into hive. However, our current version of hive 0.10 is not supporting this. so my question is can it be done in subsequent versions of hive?

Comment: Could you please show the actual query ? I'm having troubles understanding your question.

Comment: i have added the code, hope that it is understandable now.

Comment: I think it is. Would the following link answer you question ?  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries#LanguageManualSubQueries-SubqueriesintheWHEREClause

Answer (score 0):

According to the [hive wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries#LanguageManualSubQueries-SubqueriesintheWHEREClause), you can use subqueries within `WHERE` in HiveQL 0.13. However, they are still limited to `IN` and `EXISTS`, with some constraints :

> - These subqueries are only supported on the right-hand side of an expression.
> - IN/NOT IN subqueries may only select a single column.
> - EXISTS/NOT EXISTS must have one or more correlated predicates.
> - References to the parent query are only supported in the WHERE clause of the subquery.